# something wrong about execCommand

Tags: javascript

```
<select onchange="setFontSize(this)">
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
</select>
<div id="pannel" contenteditable="true">
```

html like this.

```
function setFontSize(obj){
        document.execCommand("fontSize",false,obj.value)
}
```

js like this.

And i have some questions.

1. fontsize does't work as I think(I mean the value of select has no effeft on fontsize )
2. `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange=setFontSize(this)` wont' work(separate js from html)

Comment: Those aren't questions.

Comment: `document.execCommand("fontSize", aShowDefaultUI, aValueArgument)` only accepts [HTML font sizes (1-7)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: @torazaburo I just want to know something about rich-text editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fonts only from range 1-7. [Look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

```js
function setFontSize(obj){
        document.execCommand("fontSize",false,obj.value)
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
 
<select onchange="setFontSize(this)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="3" selected>3</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div id="pannel" contenteditable="true">
Select this text and change select option.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

**fontSize**
Changes the font size for the selection or at the insertion point. This requires an integer from 1-7 as a value argument.

You can use

**styleWithCSS**